# Several simulated connections on a database impact

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I created a little Php API that connects to my db with `PDO` with a code that looks like this one:

```php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbName . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

My question is: if there are a lot of users connecting to my API at the same time, will there be a problem with the connection to my database? Will requests get lost since the same script is called many times at the same time?

Comment: I would rather remove the persistent connection and make sure this connection is created only once per script execution. This is all you can do on the PHP part. The rest depends on your servers' configuration and payload

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks :) My connection to the db is written only once in an object that I then use in my other scripts. So I think it's okay, right? For payload I'm not there yet but it was just to be already safe with php

Comment: it is not how many times the connection is written in the object. It is how many times you are creating this object during the script execution

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ah so once for each script call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDO objects are bound to the process who created it, so even though you have many processes concurrently serving requests, they do not share a single one connection, so it will not cause race condition, so no connection lose problem would occur.